# AWS cloudWatch synthetics: unable to load all dependencies in synthetics canary even after uploading it in s3 bucket with zip file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk-typescript, amazon-cloudwatch-synthetics

For creating AWS cloudwatch synthetics to monitor health check of APIs. I am using s3 bucket to upload the node js script in the following structure nodejs/node_modules/myCanaryFolder/myCanaryFile.js With all dependencies required in that file to run the api script enclosed in same folder and zip it. But still getting module not found for required dependencies.

I tried to upload the zip file manually in s3 bucket. Canary is reading but script file but not loading dependencies.

I want to run the script successfully.

Answer (score 0):

AWS CloudWatch Synthetics requires a very particular directory structure that seems to be slightly different from those of normal AWS Lambda functions.

For example, let's say you have a canary that wants to import `aws-sdk`.

First off, your zip file needs to have the below structure. The canary is placed under `node_modules` with its dependencies.

```
canary.zip
└── nodejs/
    └── node_modules/
        ├── canary/
        |   └── index.js
        └── aws-sdk
        └── [other-dependencies]
```

A folder name and entrypoint name other than *canary* and *index.js* can be used but need to match the handler name we'll set later.

Secondly, your main JavaScript entrypoint (*canary/index.js*) needs to export a handler function. Dependencies can just be imported normally. E.g.:

```
// index.js

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const log = require("SyntheticsLogger");

const runCheck = async () => {
  log.info(`AWS SDK version: ${AWS.VERSION}`);
  // ...
}

exports.handler = async () => {
  return await runCheck();
};
```

Finally, your handler needs to be in the format of `[folderName/]fileName.functionName`, where *folderName* is the folder that contains your canary script (if any), *fileName* matches the Javascript file you want to run, and *functionName* matches the exported function you want invoked.

In this example our hander will be: `canary/index.handler`, which correspond to the folder name (`canary`), file name (`index.js`), and exported handler function name (`handler`).

Reference:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Synthetics_Canaries_WritingCanary_Nodejs.html#CloudWatch_Synthetics_Canaries_package